# Jhipster project loading error

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, jhipster

i've a Jhipster project project which when i am loading to Netbeans IDE.Ican't run it.It's showing "unloadable project" on hovering over to project window.
Iam completely new to this Jipster technology. So if anybody can tell me how do i properly load and run this project .it will be helpfull for me.

Comment: Are you using Maven or Gradle for your build tool? If you use Maven, you should be able to import it as a Maven project.

Comment: which IDE should I use to work with Jhipster?

Comment: I prefer IntelliJ, but you can also use Eclipse: https://jhipster.github.io/configuring_ide.html

Comment: can you explain the program structure of jhipster? @Matt Raible

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you rephrase? You might also try reading the JHipster Mini-Book: http://www.infoq.com/minibooks/jhipster-mini-book